# leaderstats not working (Never thought they won't)

Tags: lua, roblox

So, my leaderstats is not working. It should create a folder inside my player, but it doesn't.
Tried some things to fix, but nothing helped. (This intelligent Ai doesn't want me to post this again)
Here are all of my code in leaderstats:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")
local ServerStorage
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local toolConfig = require(ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("Config"):FindFirstChild("ToolConfig"))
local dataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("Test")
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)

    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player

    local rebirths = Instance.new("NumberValue")
    rebirths.Name = "Rebirths"
    rebirths.Parent = leaderstats
    
    local cash = Instance.new("NumberValue")
    cash.Name = "Cash"
    cash.Parent = leaderstats
    local rebirths
    local cash


    rebirths = dataStore:GetAsync(player.UserId.."_Rebirths")
    cash = dataStore:GetAsync(player.UserId.."_Cash")



    if rebirths ~= nil then 
        player.leaderstats.Rebirths.Value = rebirths
    end

    if cash ~= nil then 
        player.leaderstats.Cash.Value = cash
    end
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local succes, errormsg = pcall(function()
        dataStore:SetAsync(player.UserId.."_Rebirths", player.leaderstats.Rebirths.Value)
        dataStore:SetAsync(player.UserId.."_Cash", player.leaderstats.Cash.Value)

    end) 
    if errormsg then
        print ("Data error!")
    end
end)
```

Comment: Where is this script located?

Comment: In serverScriptService

Comment: You shouldn't be adding filler text to your question to make the ai happy, you could have instead explained in more detail what "tired some things" entailed or better explained the current behavior rather than just saying "but it doesn't"

Answer (score 2):

[1: You forgot to assign serverstorage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwMM4.png)
2. Based directly off the code, it seems like the code is on Roblox.  You made the mistake of forgetting to check the developer console.  That should help.